# After append element on array it only show on append method and empty when we call from another method swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

After append element on array it only show on append method and empty when we call from another method swift 3

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let JSONUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
var JSONData: JSON = nil

var JSONDataUserId = [Int]()
var JSONDataId = [Int]()
var JSONDataTitle = [String]()
var JSONDataBody = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    getDataFromJSON(url: JSONUrl)
    dispalyData()
}

func getDataFromJSON(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let data):
            self.JSONData = JSON(data)
            for i in 0..<self.JSONData.count{
                self.JSONDataUserId.append(self.JSONData[i]["userId"].intValue)
                self.JSONDataId.append(self.JSONData[i]["id"].intValue)
                self.JSONDataTitle.append(self.JSONData[i]["title"].stringValue)
                self.JSONDataBody.append(self.JSONData[i]["body"].stringValue)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error Due to \(error)")
        }
        print(self.JSONDataUserId)

    }
}

func displayData() {

    print(self.JSONDataUserId)
}
```

}

In above method getDataFromJson the statement print(self.JSONDataUserId) work and display data, but method displayData  print(self.JSONDataUserId) display nothing. I want same result from displayData method too.

Comment: Which of them prints first?

Comment: getDataFromJSON method statement print result but  displayData method statement show JSONDataUserId as empty

Answer (score 2):

You are using async block of code so try this. you are sending a server request then getdatafrom server method is called in parallel. For more check it [Apple Api Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch)

```
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire 
    import SwiftyJSON

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let JSONUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    var JSONData: JSON = nil

    var JSONDataUserId = [Int]()
    var JSONDataId = [Int]()
    var JSONDataTitle = [String]()
    var JSONDataBody = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        getDataFromJSON(url: JSONUrl)  { success, data in
             if success {
                for i in 0..< data.count{
                    self.JSONDataUserId.append(self.JSONData[i]["userId"].intValue)
                    self.JSONDataId.append(self.JSONData[i]["id"].intValue)
                    self.JSONDataTitle.append(self.JSONData[i]["title"].stringValue)
                    self.JSONDataBody.append(self.JSONData[i]["body"].stringValue)
                }
                dispalyData()
             }

        }

    }

    func getDataFromJSON(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, JSON) -> ()) {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let data):
                completionHandler(true, JSON(data))
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error Due to \(error)")
                completionHandler(false, nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func displayData() {

        print(self.JSONDataUserId)
    }
}
```